# SQL - Populating multiple variables in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to load multiple variables in the same query like this

```
declare @currentUserPersonnelNumber int
declare @draftWorkFlowStatusId int 
declare @diWorkFlowStatusId int 
declare @ibWorkFlowStatusId int 
declare @ipWorkFlowStatusId int 

select 
    @draftWorkFlowStatusId = case when WFStep='DR' then WorkFlowId else NULL end,
    @diWorkFlowStatusId = case when WFStep='DI' then WorkFlowId else NULL end,
    @ibWorkFlowStatusId = case when WFStep='IB' then WorkFlowId else NULL end,
    @ipWorkFlowStatusId = case when WFStep='IP' then WorkFlowId else NULL end
 from WorkFlow
```

But only second variable `@diWorkFlowStatusId` is getting populated and not all.

What is wrong am I doing?

When I do it this way all the variable gets loaded properly, but I think that is not the right way

```
declare @draftWorkFlowStatusId int = (SELECT WorkFlowId FROM [WorkFlow] WHERE WFStep = 'DR')
declare @diWorkFlowStatusId int = (SELECT WorkFlowId FROM [WorkFlow] WHERE WFStep = 'DI') 
declare @ibWorkFlowStatusId int = (SELECT WorkFlowId FROM WorkFlow WHERE WFStep = 'IB') 
declare @ipWorkFlowStatusId int = (SELECT WorkFlowId FROM WorkFlow WHERE WFStep = 'IP')
```

Comment: I dont see any issue with your query case query ,except  variable output will be overridden by last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use an aggregation function :

```
declare @currentUserPersonnelNumber int
declare @draftWorkFlowStatusId int 
declare @diWorkFlowStatusId int 
declare @ibWorkFlowStatusId int 
declare @ipWorkFlowStatusId int 

select 
    @draftWorkFlowStatusId = MAX(case when WFStep='DR' then WorkFlowId end),
    @diWorkFlowStatusId = MAX(case when WFStep='DI' then WorkFlowId end),
    @ibWorkFlowStatusId = MAX(case when WFStep='IB' then WorkFlowId end),
    @ipWorkFlowStatusId = MAX(case when WFStep='IP' then WorkFlowId end)
 from WorkFlow
```

Your select as consturcted , can get only a single variable value at a time, since each of this variables are evaluated each time for each record, therefore - the `MAX()`

If there are more then 1 record that answer the critiria `WFStep = ?` , then you should tell us which one of them you want.

Comment: Excellent!! Thanks! The only thing is it is giving this warning in the message `Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.`

Comment: @PawanNogariya That's OK, I'm not sure why this warning is occuring but not problem with this query, also note that you don't have to use `ELSE NULL` since its the default `ELSE` .

Comment: Got it! One more thing, is this the efficient way to load variables or you suggest something else better?

Comment: I can't think of any better way of doing this @PawanNogariya

Comment: Ok, Thanks! I am waiting when it will allow me to select the answer correct. 2 more mins to go ... :)

Comment: does this mean .."But only second variable @diWorkFlowStatusId is getting populated and not all" you are getting nulls

Comment: @TheGameiswar - My issue is resolved with sagi's answer. Thanks :)

Comment: I understand max will eliminate nulls,but i was trying to intrepret what does the above statement in your question mean ?

Comment: Yes, that's what he meant @thegameiswar

Answer (score 0):

It's setting all your variables for every row retrieved from workflow.  If only diWorkflowStatusId is set at the end, it's because your last row has WFStep = 'DI'.

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns multiple records, in which case the variables are populated with the values of the last record selected (since you don't give an `order by` clause it's unpredictable which record that is. Apparently, it's the record where `WFStep='DI'`).